# How can I delete or disable the default SSL settings in WebSphere?

Tags: ssl, websphere

I have a Java handler which should call a SSL configuration in WAS but it always calls the default one (NodeDefaultSSLSettings).

How can I delete or disable this configuration? Can I customize anything in the WAS console in order my handler to call the correct SSL configuration instead of the default one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can override this setting under

**SSL certificate and key management > Manage endpoint security configurations > server1**

If youhave added your certificate or created a new one using websphere you will see the alias in the "**Certificate alias in key store**" dropdown , select the alias and check the "**Override inherited values**" checkbox [image]"

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response, but I don't see any "server1" option in the menu.

Thanks again!